# DisclosureGroup issues when placed inside of a ForEach in a List

Tags: swiftui

When I use a DisclosureGroup inside of a ForEach in a list, I experience issues with the animation when I tap on the last cell in a given iteration of the ForEach as long as it's not the final iteration.

For example, the issue happens when I tap on the first two occurrences of `Info 3`, but not the third occurrence. The animation in this case appears choppy, where the `Detail 3` text appears, but the indentation from the `listStyle` happens after the cell is fully visible. This issue does not happen when any other cells are tapped.

Another issue is that when I tap on the first two occurrences of `Detail 3`, they toggle the visibility of the subsequent `Detail 1` cell as though I had tapped on the `Info 1` cell.

When I place DisclosureGroups in a list without using a ForEach, none of these issues occur.

Is there an alternate approach I could use to expand cells in a List without using DisclosureGroup and without writing the animations and state changes myself?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<3) { index in
                DisclosureGroup {
                    Text("Detail 1")
                } label: {
                    Text("Info 1")
                }
                DisclosureGroup {
                    Text("Detail 2")
                } label: {
                    Text("Info 2")
                }
                DisclosureGroup {
                    Text("Detail 3")
                } label: {
                    Text("Info 3")
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.inset)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this behaviour is not intentional. It seems like adding any other row after the last disclosure group in the `ForEach` fixes the issue.

```
DisclosureGroup {
    Text("Detail 3")
} label: {
    Text("Info 3")
}
Text("Something")
```

One thing you can try is to use a `Divider` with list row separator hidden, as the last row, so that the last row resembles a normal list row separator.

```
List {
    ForEach(...) {
        ...
        Divider()
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            // add some appropriate insets to make it look like a normal row separator
            .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
    }
}
// make the divider row as short as possible
.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
```

Wrapping the all the disclosure groups in a `Section` also fixes this.

```
Section {
    DisclosureGroup { ... } label: { ... }
    DisclosureGroup { ... } label: { ... }
    DisclosureGroup { ... } label: { ... }
}
```

For non-grouped list styles, the section headers are invisible, so your list will look the same as before.