# NavigationSplitView crashes if I select an item in the sidebar after I removed other items

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationsplitview, navigationsplitview

My NavigationSplitView crashes if I select an item in the sidebar after I removed other items: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1c44d488c)

How to reproduce:

- Launch the app from the attached project: https://gist.github.com/alpennec/a45f5ff94382dc922718906a60a35220
- Tap on “Add”
- Select the new added item in the sidebar
- In the detail view, tap “Delete”
- Select “All” in the sidebar

The app crashes: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1c44d488c)

It occurs if I use just Strings or Core Data objects (I tried with plain String because I thought it was maybe an issue with Core Data but it’s not apparently).

What is wrong? Is that a bug?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FB_SwiftUI_NavigationSplitView_Delete_SelectApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

enum SelectionString: Hashable {
    case all
    case item(String)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectionString: SelectionString?
    @State private var strings: [String] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selectionString) {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink(value: SelectionString.all) {
                        Text("All")
                    }
                }
            
                Section {
                    ForEach(strings.sorted(), id: \.self) { string in
                        NavigationLink(value: SelectionString.item(string)) {
                            Text(string)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button("Add") {
                        strings.append(UUID().uuidString)
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            if let selectionString {
                switch selectionString {
                case .all:
                    Text("All")
                
                case .item(let string):
                    Button(role: .destructive) {
                        if let index = strings.firstIndex(of: string) {
                            strings.remove(at: index)
                            self.selectionString = nil
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Delete")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Text("Select an item")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should include all the code needed to reproduce the problem in the question.

Comment: Chicken and egg problem : if you remove the item from the array the line become invalid and what it triggers also. Try to put the remove in a dispatch async so it execute after the end of closure. And also string may not be good for loop if you do not make sure these are unique.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a SwiftUI bug. The problem can be reproduced on iOS, but not on macOS. If I replace the `NavigationLink`s with simple `Text`s, it works as expected:

```
Section {
    Text("All").tag(SelectionString.all)
}

Section {
    ForEach(strings.sorted(), id: \.self) { string in
        Text(string).tag(SelectionString.item(string))
    }
}
```

Putting them in the same section, switching the order of the sections, or putting another section after the `ForEach` section, all fixes the problem. This leads me to believe that this might be (at least partly) caused by the same bug as [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77108981/5133585), which is also related to the last row of a `List` behaving weirdly.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper. On my side, I too realized the issue is actually caused by the use of Section. If I keep my same code I shared but remove the sections, I don’t have the issue anymore. If I keep at least one section, it crashes. I filed a feedback for this issue.